# Send EMail in Sharepoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I want to send an Email in Sharepoint online. I used the following method to send the mail using the Event reciever.

```
 SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, headers, bodyText.ToString());
```

But it does not work with sharepoint online 2013. 
After reading in the articles I got to know that SPUtility method cannot be used. Please provide me a solution to send mail through event reciever. I am creating it as a Sandbox Solution.

Can we Use Microsoft Exchange Server? How Can I use it?

Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a workaround by leveraging the `SendMail` activity in a workflow. This is also explained here: [Guru Tip: Sending an Email in Office 365](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/04/send-an-email-in-office-365.aspx).

Unfortunately using this workflow workaround will be your only choice as both `SPUtility.SendEmail` as well as `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` are not allowed in Sandboxed solutions which is also explained in this post: [Send email via code in Office365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20552/send-email-via-code-in-office365)

Answer (score 0):

How to import Emails or part of the Email data to Sharepoint libraries or Sharepoint lists you can find on  ["The smart way from mailbox to Sharepoint"](http://www.mailtosharepoint.net). It works fine for Sharepoint online.